# Jolt Transformation order of fields

Tags: json, jolt

I've following input JSON

```json
{
  "NAME1": "Mueller",
  "NAME2": "Max",
  "STREET1": "Adlerstr.",
  "STREET2": "1",
  "COUNTRY": "Munich"
}
```

I renamed the name of the fields and concatinate the street* fields

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "NAME1": "name",
      "NAME2": "surName",
      "STREET1": "tmp_street1",
      "STREET2": "tmp_street2",
      "COUNTRY": "country"
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "modify-default-beta",
    "spec": {
      "street": "=concat(@(1,tmp_street1),' ',@(1,tmp_street2))"
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "remove",
    "spec": {
      "tmp_*": ""
    }
  }
]
```

I getting the following output

```json
{
  "name" : "Mueller",
  "surName" : "Max",
  "country" : "Munich", // Should be after the street field 
  "street" : "Adlerstr. 1" 
}
```

Is it possible to move the **`street`** field on the ***3**rd* position in the JSON output ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, street field can be moved to the 3rd position of the json output, with only two operations.

Check this spec,

```
[
  {
    "operation": "modify-default-beta",
    "spec": {
      "street": "=concat(@(1,STREET1),' ',@(1,STREET2))"
    }
},
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "NAME1": "name",
      "NAME2": "surName",
      "street": "street",
      "COUNTRY": "country"
    }
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

As another option, you can tile the attributes in the desired order by using **shift** as the first transformation while combining the values for **`STREET`** under common array renamed **`street`**.

Then apply the **overwrite** type of **modify** transformation along with ***join*** function to replace the array with a concatenated string such as

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "N*1": "name",
      "N*2": "surName",
      "S*": {
        "@(1,&)": "street"
      },
      "*": "country"
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "s*": "=join(' ',@(1,&))"
    }
  }
]
```